# Extracting and exporting (file transfer) SQL query from automation/data extension in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-extract

There is a database extension in salesforce marketing cloud that I need to export from the automation. I didn't create the DE and am unsure how to export it for use outside of salesforce marketing cloud. It is from a SQL query. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you. Would anyone be able to provide help extracting and exporting (file transfer) SQL query from automation/data extension in Marketing Cloud? Below are some screenshots:

Optout/subscriber automation

[image]

[image]

3.

Comment: Do you want to export the data from the data extension or do you want to send the data to the FTP? Also, please share only screenshots and not the links to your org (No one can access it without credentials, but might cause security issue)